# deps.json does not exist in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, ef-core-2.1

I'm creating a new project DB First in ASP.NET Core 2 with Razor Pages and when I try to generate the code from the existing DB -

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=server\V;Database=tblIssues;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I receive this error -

> The specified deps.json [filepath] does not
>   exist.

I've checked the file path and the `deps.json` file does exist. Is this related to permissions ?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you running the command from the same directory that your project is in?

Comment: @user1011627 I m using the Package manager to run the scaffold-dbContext command.

Comment: ok...I have only ever run from powershell so not familiar with running it from PM console.  What version of EFCore tools is the project using?

Comment: it appears there is a bug around scaffolding and VS2017 and people are having to copy their bin directories to a subdirectory called MCD....take a look at these links.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30116/scaffolding-error-aspnet-core-with-entity-framewor.html

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7077

Comment: @user1011627 EFCore.Tools version 2.1.1

Comment: Also, are you attempting to create the DbContext in a separate DLL or directly in the ASP.NET web app?

Comment: Also, can you verify that the tools are installed correctly?   You can run the following command to verify:   dotnet ef.   You should see a pretty text based unicorn if they are.

Comment: @user1011627 - 1. Yes, I see the unicorn. It is installed correctly. 2)  I want to create the DB Context in the same web app. 3. My error message says the correct file path didnt contain the file .deps. I think it doesnt have permission to the path. But i dont know how to fix that.

Comment: Have you tried running the command with the verbose flag?   Not sure if it will tell you any more than what the error is already spitting out but it's worth a try.   I just created a new Core 2 project and ran from Package Mgr without any issue using EF 2.1.1 so looks like it is specific to your scenario.

Comment: Are you on a Mac or PC?

Comment: @user1011627 yes I have tried this in my personal pc and it worked. It s failing on my work PC - hence something to do with permissions. but i dont know what/how.

Comment: @user1011627 - Hi User, Thanks a lot for your support - Finally figured it out :) I was running on Documents folder where visual studio and the projects were placed. I didnt have permissions there and hence had to move to C:\ - Fixed it

Comment: @user1011627, am using a mac with this issue, can kindly help?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris - Sorry, I don't ever use a Mac so not going to be much help to you.

Comment: I got the solution @user1011627